# Add value to nonzero elements of symbolic matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I would like to add a certain placeholder `O` to any nonzero element of a matrix. The matrix has elements which are not number but complicated symbolic expressions. 
Take for example:

`A = {{1 + x^3, Tan[y]}, {y^3, 0}};`

Following the solution outlined here, I tried

`B = A /. {x_ /; x != 0 :> x + O} // MatrixForm`

But this evidently replaces adds O to any **number** within the matrix:

`{{1 + O + x^(3 + O), Tan[y]}, {y^(3 + O), 0}}`

How could that be modified to make it work in that case as well?
The output I am after is:

`{{1 + x^3 +O, Tan[y]+O}, {y^3+O, 0}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output I am after is: {{1 + x^3 +O, Tan[y]+O}, {y^3+O, 0}}

One way might be

```
ClearAll[x,O];
A = {{1 + x^3, Tan[y]}, {y^3, 0}}
newA = Map[If[# =!= 0, # + O, #] &, A, {2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Using an undocumented way of constructing `SparseArray`s:

```
A = {{1 + x^3, Tan[y]}, {y^3, 0}};
AO = Normal@With[{a = SparseArray[A]},
   SparseArray @@ {Automatic, Dimensions[a], a["Background"], {1, {
       a["RowPointers"],
       a["ColumnIndices"]
       },
      a["NonzeroValues"] + O}}
   ]
```

> {{1 + O + x^3, O + Tan[y]}, {O + y^3, 0}}